# Doctrine remove owning side Many To Many relation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, many-to-many, relation

I have this relation between 2 Entities in Symfony 3:

```
class Project
{
    /**
    * @var int
    *
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    private $id;

    /**
    * @var ArrayCollection
    *
    * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Neighborhood", inversedBy="projects")
    * @ORM\JoinTable(name="neighborhood_project")
    */
    private $neighborhoods;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->neighborhoods = new ArrayCollection;
    }

    public function getNeighborhoods()
    {...}

    public function setNeighborhoods(array $entities)
    {...}

    public function addNeighborhood(Neighborhood $entity)
    {...}

    public function removeNeighborhood(Neighborhood $entity)
    {...}
}

class Neighborhood
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false, unique=true)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Project", mappedBy="neighborhoods")
     */
    private $projects;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->projects = new ArrayCollection;
    }

    public function getProjects()
    {...}

    public function setProjects(array $entities)
    {...}

    public function addProject(Project $entity)
    {...}

    public function removeProject(Project $entity)
    {...}
}
```

This works fine. But Problem that I have, is removing the relations.

**$em->remove($neighborhood);** delete the neighborhood in the table '**neighborhood**' and all relations in the table '**neighborhood_project**'.

**$em->remove($project);** delete the project in the table '**project**' and **DOES NOT** delete the relation in the table '**neighborhood_project**'.

I have tried many options to delete the relation on the owning side and didn't found any solution.
How can i delete the relation on deleting the owning side?

Added:

Cascade:

```
@ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Neighborhood", inversedBy="projects", cascade={"remove"})
```

won't help. This will delete entity, relation and related entities.
I need same functionality like **$em->remove($neighborhood);**

Comment: did you try onDelete="CASCADE" ? regards

Comment: Yes, I have tried it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have it, my fault.
I should just update the schema in database (doctrine:schema:update).